# How can I access an object property set within an initializer?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, initialization

I don't know if this is even possible, but how can I access an object property that has be set within an initializer so that I can use it to set another property within the same initializer?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
var usersWithCount =
    users
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(
        u =>
        new User()
            {
                UserId = u.UserId,
                UserName = u.UserName,
                Email = u.Email,
                RelatedId = u.RelatedId,
                ReviewCount = u.Reviews.Count(r => !r.Deleted && r.Approved),
                HelpfulYesCount = u.Reviews.Where(r => !r.Deleted && r.Approved).Sum(r => r.HelpfulYes),
                HelpfulNoCount = u.Reviews.Where(r => !r.Deleted && r.Approved).Sum(r => r.HelpfulNo),
                TotalPoints = ReviewCount + HelpfulYesCount - HelpfulNoCount,
                DateCreated = u.DateCreated
            })
    .OrderByDescending(user => user.TotalPoints);
```

The part that doesn't work is "TotalPoints = ReviewCount + HelpfulYesCount - HelpfulNoCount".  I'd rather avoid using "u.Reviews.Count(r => !r.Deleted && r.Approved)" again and I'd don't want to have to loop through the results to add those values together to set TotalPoints.

How can I reference those properties within the initializer that were set above the TotalPoints property?  Is there some way I can set them equal to variables and reference them where they are set and where I'm trying to add them?  Am I approaching this situation the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you could do

```
...
.Select( u => {
    var rc = u.Reviews.Count(...);
    var hyc = ...;
    ...
    return new User() { /*now reference precomputed vars rc, hyc, ...*/ };})
...
```

though perhaps there is another/better way.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you change the TotalPoints property of your User class to return a calculated value? e.g.

```
public int TotalPoints
{
  get
  {
    return ReviewCount + HelpfulYesCount - HelpfulNoCount
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the User object is created on the fly

Comment: Ok, but surely you must have a class definition for the User object somewhere?

Comment: The User object was created on the fly but I actually added these properties to the object.  I tried this option and it did work, but decided to go with Brian's suggestion since the User object is the only object I've added properties to and I might want to do this to a property of an object I haven't added custom properties to.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basically the same as Brian's answer, but in query expression instead of extension methods

```
from users.AsEnumerable()
let reviewCount = u.Reviews.Count(...)
let helpfulYesCount = u.Reviews.Count(...)
let ...
select new User
{
   ReviewCount = reviewCount,
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need two levels for this.  Enumerable #1 to calculate your base counts, Enumerable #2 (what you return to consolidate the counts).